# What plane is most similar to the LEGO Firefighter Aircraft 42152?

Tags: aircraft-identification, airplane, firefighting

I want to identify a LEGO Firefighter Aircraft: [LEGO set #42152](https://kubiki.ge/lego/firefighter-aircraft/)

Is this model based on a real plane? Does anyone have any ideas?

[image: LEGO Firefighter Aircraft 42152]

Answer (score 31):

I don't think this is a replica of an *actual model of aircraft*, however I believe that this set has taken a lot of inspiration from the [Canadair CL-415](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadair_CL-415) both in the design and more so in the color scheme.

[image]

The only other real example of a twin prop aircraft used for firefighting is the [Antonov AN-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-32) and that doesn't share any more characteristics with the set than the Canadair, and certainly doesn'tt match the paint scheme.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

While it could be any of the previous aircraft from the other answers, I would suggest that it is a DHC Dash 8 water bomber. Both are twin turboprops with a t-tail configuration.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is supported by the Lego model's main landing gears being attached to the engine pods, which is a characteristic of the Dash 8. The CL-415 MLG is fuselage-mounted.

Comment: Yeah, I think the Dash-8 is a good shout, I didn't even think of that one.

Answer (score 14):

That's for sure a nice mixture inspired from the turboprop-powered airplanes by De Havilland Aircraft of Canada (DHC).

In particular, the airframe looks like the one of a [DHC-8](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Havilland_Canada_Dash_8) aka Dash 8: T-tail, landing gears retracting in the nacelles, tapered wingtips and general proportions they all point in that direction:

[image: Dash-8]

The paint job is anyway unmistakably the one of their firefighting flying boats, like the [CL-215](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadair_CL-215) or [-415](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canadair_CL-415)

[image: CL-215]

The flat red belly seems to have also been taken from this latter.

[image: Lego 42152]
(*[Picture source](https://www.avenuedelabrique.com/img/produits/42152/thumbs/42152-l-avion-de-lutte-contre-l-incendie-6-1672906629_1000x0.jpg)*)

I suppose they've kept the set unlicensed in order to leave the price as low as possible. They did a nice mix, have fun with that set

---

*All other pictures from Wikipedia*

Comment: You can make the propeller spin with a lever in the belly?! That is too cool.

Answer (score 9):

Near as I know, the aircraft featured in that technic kit may be a generic looking “water bomber” that is not an exact match for an actual aircraft currently in service. From the color scheme and lines of the aircraft, it is very similar to a [Viking Aircraft DHC 515](https://dehavilland.com/en/news/posts/de-havilland-aircraft-of-canada-limited-launches-dhc-515-firefighter), which is based upon DeHavilland/Canadair’s CL215/415 series of amphibious aerial firefighting aircraft.

[image]

The DHC 515 is a large aircraft, nearly the size of a 737, specifically designed for loitering over wilderness terrain near hotspots, then can make deliveries of up to 1600 gallons of water on a fire with or without chemical retardant added.  It can then go scoop another 1600 gallons of water directly out of a nearby lake and return to the loiter area. This gives the aircraft probably the greatest versatility for fighting wildfires out of any airframe out there.

The Lego Technic model appears to match the DHC 515 in terms of the shape of the nose as well as it is a high wing design but does not appear to feature the ‘flying boat’ fuselage superstructure and the outrigger floats nor the cruciform design of the empennage that the Viking DHC 515 features.

Comment: *Nearly the size of a 737* Not quite. Yes on wingspan. But comparing to 737 Classic, MTOW for 737 is about 3x, and length about 1.5x the DHC515.

Comment: Dimension wise, that’s pretty comparable to a 737 Classic. The slugs were heavier, mind you, but the DeHavilland ‘Ducks’ aren’t light either!

Comment: The 737 is much longer - about 100 ft even for the Classic, versus 66 ft for the DHC-515. The Boeing's cabin is also 4 times the size. They're only similar in wingspan, and only because the Boeing's wing is swept. Next to one another, it would be obvious one's much larger. Now, the Beriev Be-200, that's a 737-sized amphibian.

Comment: I think the phraseology was nearly the size of a 737. At any rate, it doesn’t matter.